# How to only require sinatra/base using Bundler?

Tags: bundler

I'm only need `sinatra/base`, but I don't know how to do it by using bundler. Because in the `Gemfile` I can't give it 'sinatra/base', but the gem name `sinatra` instead.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax in your Gemfile:

```
 gem "sinatra", "X.Y.Z", :require => "sinatra/base"
```

You can then require it via bundler using the #require method:

```
Bundler.require :default
```